# ASP.NET - collaboration between designer and developer

Tags: asp.net, dreamweaver, collaboration

Our organization has dedicated designers who design the page and cut it up in Dreamweaver.  That's worked well in the past with ASP and PHP sites.  Now we're trying to make it work with .NET, but are struggling because of the structure of a project in ASP.NET.  How does everybody collaborate with developers?  The specific points I am looking for are:

-Transferring Dreamweaver content to Visual Studio
-Changing HTML inputs to server controls
-Giving designer access to finished Visual Studio product so they can tweak layout

Thanks!

Comment: Dreamweaver can be set up to handle ASP.NET 1.1 sites. I haven't seen a version of DW that can handle MasterPages. To me that is what is going to make your life a living Heck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, there will be a slight learning curve for your designers. But with that said, I have worked quite often with designers (none of whom used Dreamweaver, btw, so that may be part of the problem) on asp.net sites. Usually, they will create the HTML exactly how they want it on the server like a static HTML page, then I will go in and replace form fields manually with asp.net controls.

On an aside, I have found that I have the best chance of matching the design using controls that spit out the least HTML, such as Repeaters instead of DataGrids.

Once the site is up on the server and programmed, they can go back in an tweak things if need be.

Also, just like we have to adapt to them a bit (making our server controls spit out html how they like it) they also have to adapt to us a bit and not rely as heavily on id attributes in their stylesheets as some items id attributes will be controlled by hte .net runtime since they are controls.

MOre often than not, a designer new to asp.net will feel very threatened by this new way of doing things, specially with user controls instad of include files, but its really not that different than classic asp/php development is.

Answer (score 0):

The key to the solution of all your problems in this matter is quite simple, and yet so hard to fulfill: it's usually called [**semantic markup**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Semantic_HTML). If you can make sure that the designers to start with make their html semantic, and that the .Net programmers keep rendering the same markup but with their server controls where needed, the tweaking won't be a problem - the markup is the same.

So what is semantic html, then? you may ask. Well, it's not always as simple as one would like it to be. A good start is to make every page [pass XHTML validation](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Not to disparage semantics, but that's not the answer to this particular problem.

Comment: Maybe not, but there is still something to what Tomas is saying here. If the designers do use semantic layouts, then there will be much more "barren" with less moving parts to coordinate (and all the design will be contained within the css).  And as he mentioned, its easier said than done.

Comment: Joel, as I understood the problem, it was that in the current ways of working it's hard do do a smooth handover from designers to programmers and back again. If so, even though semantic (x)html does not specifically address the problem of differences between DW and VS, it does indirectly solve the problems of design/programming compatibility, which is what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, designer-created HTML almost always needs to be at least refactored, if not rewritten. So, open a browser with the original HTML on the left, and try to match it as closely as possible in VS on the right screen.

Giving designers access to ASP markup is not a good idea, imho. Too much can go wrong if you only understand half of the tags you are manipulating.

Comment: See, I would disagree. You are a team and you need to be able to trust your designers with your work just like they trust you with theirs. And, hopefully, you are also using revision control and can revert any catastrophic failures. If you play access and trust games with other team members, they will never become a full part of the team and you are left doing all the work.

Comment: I am talking about my practical experience over 10 years in the industry. Designers are not part of the development team, and do not partake in the (iterative) development process. In every single instance where I worked with a design team there was a very clean one-time hand-off and rarely a need for the designer to go back and make adjustements.
There was, however, a frequent need to fix the HTML. Since the HTML does get substantially altered, you cannot have a soft hand-off, in my opinion. That would complicate matters, and increase development time and cost.

Answer (score 0):

How about using one of Microsoft Expressions line of products?  I've heard they are to .NET what dreamweaver is to PHP/ASP.